# Spring Boot Batch - Read Data from Database but don't want to write meta-data to database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

im developing a Spring Boot Batch App that will read data from a database and write it to a csv file.

when i tried to run it, it gets me an error : `Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

i noticed that the error is caused by the core program of spring batch trying to write to a table called batch_job_instance in the database that i connected to when i try to read data from database.

is there anyway or configuration so that the program will never need to do anything to the database that i connect to except for doing "select" query to get the data that i needed for my job?

==============================EDIT 12-08-2021====================

Hi, i've tried the method you give:

```
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Bean
    ResourcelessTransactionManager resoucelessTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(resoucelessTransactionManager());
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(createJobRepository());
        return launcher;
    }
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public Step step1(){
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step1")
                .<MT196,MT196>chunk(100)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job exportPeronJob(){
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("exportPeronJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

But still getting the same error.

Comment: While the answer by Debopam is correct, I want to mention that the Map-based job repository implementation is deprecated for removal in v5: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3780. So I would recommend using the JDBC based job repository with an in-memory database instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is configurable. We need to use MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean and ResourcelessTransactionManager.

XML Configuration

```
<bean id="appTransactionManager"
 class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="appJobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="appJobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="appJobRepository" />
</bean>
```

Java Configuration

```
@Bean
public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(
        ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager) throws Exception {

    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new 
            MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(resourcelessTransactionManager);

    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository(
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    return launcher;
}
```

Comment: While this is possible, I want to mention that the Map-based job repository implementation is deprecated for removal in v5: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3780. So I would recommend using the JDBC based job repository with an in-memory database instead.

Comment: hi Mr. Hassine, can you give me some reference on the in-memory database? so what im trying to understand is that the job will need to initiate a in-memory database first so that the job can write into that database?

Comment: another question for debopam, then how should i run it, should i just add those thing in the class of the main clasas?

Comment: Add these as configuration to the Spring job.